# How to manage multiple windows in Cocoa apps with Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, cocoa, window, nswindow

I have this application with 3 classes: AppController, Profile, ProfileBuilder. I also need 3 windows: one for each class. I tried keeping all 3 as subclasses of NSObject and applying initWithNibName to an NSWindowController class WindowController variable but when I tried outputting some values on each window it wouldn't work, and also the window resulted as null using NSLog. I was wondering what was the best way to manage multiple windows, perhaps all from a same class like an AppWindowsController involving as least as possible specific code in the other classes, and keeping, if possible, the other classes as subclasses of NSObject and not NSWindowController. So if there is, maybe a way to control the behavior of the windows remotely, adding as least as possible code inside the specific classes, just to keep them as clear as possible and uniquely focused on their content. Thanks, hope I made myself clear, I'm actually pretty new to the Cocoa framework.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to load the nib files with your windows in an init method for your different classes. For example, in Profile, you could do something like this:

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        NSArray *array;
        BOOL success = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileWindow" owner: self topLevelObjects:&array];
        if (success) {
            for (id obj in array) {
                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSWindow class]]) {
                    self.profileWindow = obj;
                }
            }
            [self.profileWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

profileWindow is a property (typed as strong). In the xib file, I set the File's Owner to Profile.

Comment: I don't understand how the array works.. How come you don't need to initialize it, and why does it already contain objects?

Comment: The method loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects: returns the array by reference. When something is returned by reference you supply the address to the object in the method (the "&array"). You see this in all the methods that return an error by reference as well. I don't need to initialize it because the method supplies the array, you just need to give it a variable to point to it.

Comment: It tells me: [NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10011da70

Comment: Look at my code again -- the message needs to be sent to [NSBundle mainBundle]. Actually, it shouldn't even compile if you did that, so I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. Why don't you post the code you're using now.

Comment: Ok so maybe I have an idea why it doesn't work.. I call the init function to Profile (after allocating an instance of it) from an AppController class. This class is in the same directory of ProfileBuilder and so is the MainMenu.xib. I was thinking maybe the problem was that there are more than one nib files in that bundle..

Comment: In my test project I created 3 new xib files (in addition to MainMenu.xib), one for each window. Each just has one window with some UI elements in it for testing. I alloc init'd the other classes in the app delegate.

Comment: Do you perhaps declare profileWindow in the header file as an IBOutlet?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17310/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-bigcola)

Comment: I have 2 window objects in same xib , I name one window indentifier as "a1" and other as "b2". Then i used predicate on the top-level objects array to find the window i want to display.  I used [[Mywindowcontroller alloc] initWithWindow:FilteredArray[0]]; to initialize self. But this causes to load both window sometimes any idea why ?

Answer (score 2):

I just like to improve the solution of rdelmar.

You don't need to iterate over the array to find the `NSWindow` class.
If you define profileWindow as an outlet and connect it in the IB, the call

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileWindow" owner:self topLevelObjects:&array];
```

will assign the window object to your outlet, the array stuff is not required.
The key here is the owner object which act as interface. In the IB you can define the class type of the owner and if so, see its outlets.

Comment: Wow. You just explained so much to me in this last paragraph. Thanks a _ton_. I've been hunting around for information on how the main nib, file's owner, and secondary nib (plus file's owner) relate and it's been driving me absolutely nutsI think I now vaguely grasp how important File's Owner is on the secondary Nib file. It's still sort of magic to me in some ways, but this definitely helps move my understanding forward. :)